# Adding Tips to Axis Lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I am trying to add arrows pointing on the axis lines for the following graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.75,line width=1pt]
\begin{axis}[
color= gray,
xmin=-4.9, 
xmax=4.9, 
ymin=-1.9, 
ymax=2.9, 
axis equal image, 
axis lines=middle, 
font=\scriptsize,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
xticklabels={}, 
yticklabels={},
legend pos=outer north east,
]

\addplot[red, smooth, domain=-4.9:4.9] {(8)/(4 + x^2)}; 
\addlegendentry{$f(x)$}

\addplot[blue, smooth, domain=-4.9:4.9]{(-16*x)/((4+x^2)^2)};
\addlegendentry{$f'(x)$}

\addplot[green, smooth, domain=-4.9:4.9]{-(((16)*((4 + x^2)^2))-((4 + x^2)* 
(64*(x^2))))/((4+x^2)^4)};
\addlegendentry{$f''(x)$}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Plotting the curve when $r=1$.}
\label{fig:1}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output of the code:

[image: axis]

See how only the top and the right end of the axis lines have arrow pointers, and the bottom and the left do not? Is there a way so I could get some on all four ends?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
every inner x axis line/.append style={stealth-stealth},
every inner y axis line/.append style={stealth-stealth},
```

at the end of your axis options, just after the `legend pos=outer north east,` and just before the `]`

See section 4.9.9 of the current [reference manual](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

If you are happy with them both being the same, you could just set a single key (as pointed out in the comments):

```
inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}
```

Comment: Slightly shorter would be `inner axis line style={stealth-stealth}`.

Comment: Great response, a quick easy solution to my problem! Much appreciated!